# the use of "would have to + V1" is correct?

Tags: modal-verbs

To make a curry, they would have to buy meat and fish, gather vegetables, and get some ghee.
In the sentence, is the use of "would have to + V1" correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please provide some context please?

Comment: There was rice enough for all of them all right.

Answer (score 1):

In this case *would have + infinitive* indicates the conditional version of *have to*. This can be followed by a conditional construction:

> They *would have* to buy meat and fish if they wanted to make a curry.